# Output of camera to TV looks terrible, but doesn't on a computer

Tags: olympus

First off, I've purchased a Olympus TG-630 iHS, brand new. I never really had much experience with cameras, I just want one that I can point and shoot, and will produce decent images. That the camera is waterproof is quite a bonus, especially at the price I got it for. 12 megapixels only, but I've been told mps are not the end-all-be-all of cameras. It got great reviews on the internet, with the worst being mediocre, which I can deal with just fine.

So, after leaving the store, taking a few shots here and there (which looks great on the camera's 3 inch screen), I plug the thing (via some kinda port to AV) to my TV and...

Well, it looks terrible. The colors bleed out from one part of the picture to another, the picture is not really sharp, there are pixels all around, etc., etc. At first I thought I just messed up the setting. But after fiddling with it, it did not improve. Plugging in my mom's 8 megapixel smartphone shows that it had better results.

Not looking good.

Now, I took the memory card and put in my computer, and the results ranged from mediocre, to decent. Exactly what I was looking for. If I zoom in using Windows Photo Viewer, it will look terrible, of course, but otherwise, completely decent.

So what gives? Is it broken? Is there something wrong with the output? I'm not sure if there's something wrong with the TV - I tried it on my neighbor's TV, with the same terrible results. Are digital cameras really just terrible on TVs? Why does an 8mp camera from a smartphone look better (on TV)?

I need to know if this is an issue. So I can return it, if there is something wrong with it.

For reference:

- My TV is a Sharp Aquos 36" (iirc), LED, 1080p
- My neighbor's TV is a Samsung, something, around 40+ inches, also 1080p.
- Laptop used for viewing is Asus N56, also 1080p.
- My camera is an Olympus TG-630 iHS, brand new. 12 Megapixels, 1080p video capable, and I'll post more details as needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is probably that you go through an analogue connection to your TV. Unless you connect using HDMI (or DVI, DisplayPort or other digital connections) you will not get good result.

If your camera doesn't have any digital output, the best idea is probably to display your photos using a computer (or connect your computer to the TV using a digital connection).

Edit: Looking up the specifications for your camera it should have a HDMI output. All you need is a HDMI cable with a HDMI D-connector to normal HDMI.

Comment: My mistake, I incorrectly assumed he was reading off the memory card. @Håkon is certainly correct that trying to display nice high resolution digital images over an analog composite channel is going to look like crap.

Comment: I asked my uncle. You were right about the analogue connection - it simply won't do. Since we didn't have an HDMI D connector, we just used the included USB cable. D'Oh!! Epic fail on my part. Works as intended now, thanks.

Comment: That won't have been a USB cable.  It sounds like the component video (yellow phono/rca).  If you'd used the USB which you use to hook up to your computer then you'd have got an on screen menu to navigate the camera contents via the remote control and the picture would have been tack sharp.

Comment: Some point and shoot cameras come with a USB-to-AV-cable, so they don't need a separate port on the camera.

Answer (score 1):

Check what video format the camera is set to output, ie NTSC or PAL. If it is set to the wrong format, your TV may not support this, which may look terrible.

NTSC is standard for most of America, while PAL is standard for Europe.

Comment: Tried setting it to PAL or NTSC. Same results.

Comment: More likely, switching to digital would make the difference, to the extent the camera can convert the size reliably.